# How to allow read-only binding to the internal properties of a custom control DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I am developing a `CustomControl` that exposes the `DependencyProperty` `SearchRange`, which is based on the custom class `Range`.

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchRangeProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SearchRange",
            typeof (Range<DateTime>),
            typeof (VariableBrowser));

    // ...

    public Range<DateTime> SearchRange
    {
        get { return (Range<DateTime>)this.GetValue(SearchRangeProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SearchRangeProperty, value); }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The class `Range` contains two different properties, `Minimum` and `Maximum`, and it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class Range<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : IComparable
{
    private T _maximum;
    private T _minimum;

    public T Maximum
    {
        get { return this._maximum; }
        set
        {
            this._maximum = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Maximum");
        }
    }

    public T Minimum
    {
        get { return this._minimum; }
        set
        {
            this._minimum = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Minimum");
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The specifications that I am following require that an application that uses my Custom control should be able to bind to the `SearchRange` property only in order to read its inner values (`Minimum` and `Maximum`), as these must be handled internally and set just by my `CustomControl`. The binding target should be updated after any variation to either the `SearchRange` property or its internal props (`Minimum` and `Maximum`), without reassigning the entire `SearchRange`.
Alternatively, I should permit to bind directly to the internal properties (`SearchRange.Minimum` and `SearchRange.Maximum`).

I tried many different ways to achieve this result, but none was successful. How could I obtain the required result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  You should be able to bind directly to those properties the same way as you bind to any other; is there a particular problem you're having, or do you not know how to use databinding?

Answer (score 0):

There should be two dependency properties for the minimuma and maximum, register a [property changed callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx). In this callback you can then construct a range from the new values and use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) on the range property (this keeps bindings intact). You could also provide a callback for the range property in which you use SetCurrentValue to update the other two properties.

Pseudo code:

```
private static void MinChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, TheRightKindOfArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyCustomControl)o;
    control.UpdateRange((DateTime)e.NewValue, Maximum);
}
private static void MaxChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, TheRightKindOfArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyCustomControl)o;
    control.UpdateRange(Minimum, (DateTime)e.NewValue);
}

private void UpdateRange(DateTime min, DateTime max)
{
    var range = new Range<DateTime>(min, max);
    SetCurrentValue(SearchRangeProperty, range);
}
```